# CSS - Any span not set width to take the remainder

Tags: css

If I something like:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <span style="width: 5%">5% Width</span>
   ... (some more here)
   <span>Fill the leftover</span>
   ... (more span with width given)
   <span style="width: 5%">5% Width</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way that the `span` (placed anywhere in the list) can fill the left over width?

Comment: you can use table & table-cell display prop of css

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Jai, please submit your comment as an answer cause that worked perfectly!

Comment: @Kousha posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use display property of `table and table-cell` to get that done this way:

```
<div style="width: 100%; display:table;">
   <span style="width: 5%; display:table-cell;">5% Width</span>
     ... (some more here)
   <span style='display:table-cell;'>Fill the leftover</span>
    ... (more span with width given)
   <span style="width: 5%; display:table-cell;">5% Width</span>
</div>
```